# How to get a e.keycode?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, keycode

I have a code:

```
var mainMenuContainer = document.getElementById('main-menu-container');
var mainMenuLinks = mainMenuContainer.getElementsByTagName('a');

function myFunction(links, i) {
    return function () {
        console.log(links[i]);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < mainMenuLinks.length; i++) {
    mainMenuLinks[i].onkeydown = myFunction(mainMenuLinks, i);
}
```

I can now get the link where the key press occurred. I still need to get the `e.keycode` of key that was pressed on the link. How to do it?
(I need to use old methods to support browsers, so the code is like this).

Comment: `return function (e) {` - add an `e`vent to the function.

Comment: [KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) is _deprecated_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To not edit your `myFunction`, you could wrap the call:

```
for (var i = 0; i < mainMenuLinks.length; i++) {
    var onKeyDownFunc = myFunction(mainMenuLinks, i);
    mainMenuLinks[i].onkeydown = function(e) {
       console.log(e.keycode);
       onKeyDownFunc();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) but I would expect a click on a link

I STRONGLY recommend

```js
const mainMenuContainer = document.getElementById("main-menu-container");
const myFunction = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.type==="keydown") console.log(e.code);
  const tgt = e.target; // or e.target.closest("a") if there are child elements of the link
  if (tgt.tagName === "A") {
    console.log(tgt.href)
  }
};
mainMenuContainer.addEventListener("keydown", myFunction); 
mainMenuContainer.addEventListener("click ", myFunction);
```

```html
<div id="main-menu-container">
  <a href="#home">Home</a> | <a href="#about">about</a>
</div>
```